# using github action to deploy a bw6 application but in TEA its starting not running

Tags: github-actions, tibco

I am using Github action pipeline to deploy a BW6 application but as per log the application is starting but in TEA its also showing starting not RUNNING

below is the log:

```
[INFO] AppName -> ee.vndrCisco.eventMsg.entEvent.application, State -> Starting
[INFO] AppName -> ee.vndrCisco.eventMsg.entEvent.application, State -> Starting
[INFO] AppName -> ee.vndrCisco.eventMsg.entEvent.application, State -> Starting
[INFO] AppName -> ee.vndrCisco.eventMsg.entEvent.application, State -> Starting
[INFO] AppName -> ee.vndrCisco.eventMsg.entEvent.application, State -> Starting
[INFO] AppName -> ee.vndrCisco.eventMsg.entEvent.application, State -> Starting
[INFO] AppName -> ee.vndrCisco.eventMsg.entEvent.application, State -> Starting
[INFO] AppName -> ee.vndrCisco.eventMsg.entEvent.application, State -> Starting
```

Though the appspace and appnode is running